# xxx is not part of the schema for this Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am facing this problem only when I use the AIDE app on Android to code (There is no problem when I use Android Studio). After I compile and install my app, when it's launches, the MainActivity stops.

> Device name: Nexus 6P (angler).
>
> Android version: 6.0.1
>
> Realm version: 1.1.0
>
> AIDE version: 3.2.160525 (Latest version).

*** Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter.i_droidi.notah/com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Notes is not part of the schema for this Realm
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5481)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Notes is not part of the schema for this Realm
at io.realm.internal.modules.CompositeMediator.getMediator(CompositeMediator.java:132)
at io.realm.internal.modules.CompositeMediator.getTableName(CompositeMediator.java:79)
at io.realm.RealmSchema.getSchemaForClass(RealmSchema.java:235)
at io.realm.RealmQuery.<init>(RealmQuery.java:136)
at io.realm.RealmQuery.createQuery(RealmQuery.java:85)
at io.realm.Realm.where(Realm.java:925)
at com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.RealmController.getNotes(RealmController.java:74)
at com.twitter.i_droidi.notah.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
... 10 more
```

*** MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    private NavigationView navigationView = null;
    private NotesAdapter adapter;
    private Realm realm;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener;
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;
    private String version;
    private TextView versionText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.realm = RealmController.with(this).getRealm();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout_drawerlayout_mainactivity);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navi_drawer_open, R.string.navi_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        try
        {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            version = packageInfo.versionName;
        }
        catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        versionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_version);
        if(versionText != null)
            versionText.setText(version);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        setupRecycler();

        setRealmAdapter(RealmController.with(this).getNotes());

...
```

*** RealmController.java:**

```
public class RealmController {

    private static RealmController instance;
    private final Realm realm;

    private RealmController(Application application)
    {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    private static RealmController with(Fragment fragment)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new RealmController(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
        }

        return instance;
    }

    protected static RealmController with(Activity activity)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new RealmController(activity.getApplication());
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private static RealmController with(Application application)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new RealmController(application);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    protected static RealmController getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    protected Realm getRealm()
    {
        return realm;
    }

    protected void refresh()
    {
        realm.waitForChange();
    }

    private void clearAll()
    {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        RealmResults<Notes> results = realm.where(Notes.class).findAll();
        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    protected RealmResults<Notes> getNotes()
    {
        return realm.where(Notes.class).findAll();
    }

    private Notes getNote(int id)
    {
        return realm.where(Notes.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    }

    protected boolean hasNotes()
    {
        return !realm.where(Notes.class).findAll().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

*** Notes.java:**

```
public class Notes extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    private String date;

    protected int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    protected void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    protected String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    protected void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    protected String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    protected void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your gradle tool version?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce v2.1.2

Comment: Is annotation processing enabled?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried it before by adding `@RealmClass` in `Notes` class, but the problem is the same.

Comment: I assume it also works if you run it from the commandline?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior How I can run it by using CommandLine?! I am using AIDE on Android.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familiar with AIDE, but as stated here as well. Most likely the annotation processor isn't running. If it is, you should see some output to the terminal saying something like "Note: Processing Notes"